# Adding :default => true to boolean in existing Rails column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I've seen a few questions (namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration)) here on SO about adding a default boolean value to an existing column. So I tried the `change_column` suggestion but I mustn't be doing it right.

I tried:

```
$ change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => true
```

Which returns `-bash: change_column: command not found`

I then ran:

```
$ rails g change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => true
```

...and

```
$ rails change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => true
```

Then ran `rake db:migrate`, but the value for `:show_attribute` remained `nil`. In the question I referenced above it says in PostgreSQL you need to update it manually. Since I'm using PostgreSQL I added the following in my `create_profiles` migration:

```
t.boolean :show_attribute, :default => true
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

`change_column` is a method of `ActiveRecord::Migration`, so you can't call it like that in the console.

If you want to add a default value for this column, create a new migration:

`rails g migration add_default_value_to_show_attribute`

Then in the migration created:

```
# That's the more generic way to change a column
def up
  change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, default: true
end

def down
  change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, default: nil
end
```

OR a more specific option:

```
def up
    change_column_default :profiles, :show_attribute, true
end

def down
    change_column_default :profiles, :show_attribute, nil
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

It won't change anything to the already created records. To do that you would have to create a `rake task` or just go in the `rails console` and update all the records (which I would not recommend in production).

When you added `t.boolean :show_attribute, :default => true` to the `create_profiles` migration, it's expected that it didn't do anything. Only migrations that have not already been ran are executed. If you started with a fresh database, then it would set the default to true.

Comment: That change_column call should be in the `up` method in the migration, which is a new class that will be generated in db/migrate/. (The `down` method should be written to undo what `up` does.) Make that change, then `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: it wasn't working for me until I wrote `def self.up` and `def self.down`

Comment: You're probably using an older version of rails then. I think this syntax is there since 3.1.

Comment: And in Rails 5, you leave off the _attribute so it should just say `show` or whatever the column name is.

Answer (score 96):

As a variation on the accepted answer you could also use the `change_column_default` method in your migrations:

```
def up
  change_column_default :profiles, :show_attribute, true
end

def down
  change_column_default :profiles, :show_attribute, nil
end
```

[Rails API-docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default)

Comment: This ensures you won't accidentally change any of the other column properties

Comment: And in Rails 5 you leave off the _attribute so it should just say `show` or whatever the column name is.

Comment: @labyrinth What do you mean? `show_attribute` *is* the name of the column, I don't think rails 5 has anything to do with that, right?

Answer (score 37):

I'm not sure when this was written, but currently to add or remove a default from a column in a migration, you can use the following:

```
change_column_null :products, :name, false
```

Rails 5:

```
change_column_default :products, :approved, from: true, to: false
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Rails 4.2:

```
change_column_default :products, :approved, false
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Which is a neat way of avoiding looking through your migrations or schema for the column specifications.

Comment: Beware, it's from Rails 5 documentation. Rails 4.2 version of this does not accept hash but exactly new default as the third parameter.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Comment: About Rails 5, doing both seems to be the most correct way, e.g. `null: false` and `default: :something` basically

Answer (score 2):

If you just made a migration, you can rollback and then make your migration again.

To rollback you can do as many steps as you want:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

Or, if you are using Rails 5.2 or newer:

```
rails db:rollback STEP=1
```

Then, you can just make the migration again:

```
def change
  add_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, default: true
end
```

Don't forget to `rake db:migrate` and if you are using heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Also, as per the doc:

> default cannot be specified via command line

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

So there is no ready-made rails generator. As specified by above answers, you have to fill manually your migration file with the `change_column_default` method.

You could create your own generator: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Answer (score 0):

```
change_column :things, :price_1, :integer, default: 123, null: false
```

Seems to be best way to add a default to an existing column that doesn't have `null: false` already.

Otherwise:

```
change_column :things, :price_1, :integer, default: 123
```

Some research I did on this:

https://gist.github.com/Dorian/417b9a0e1a4e09a558c39345d50c8c3b

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create another migration-file for a small, recent change - from Rails Console:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.change_column :profiles, :show_attribute, :boolean, :default => true
```

Then exit and re-enter rails console, so DB-Changes will be in-effect.  Then, if you do this ...

```
Profile.new()
```

You should see the "show_attribute" default-value as true.

For existing records, if you want to preserve existing "false" settings and only update "nil" values to your new default:

```
Profile.all.each{|profile| profile.update_attributes(:show_attribute => (profile.show_attribute == nil ? true : false))  }
```

Update the migration that created this table, so any future builds of the DB will get it right from the onset.  Also run the same process on any deployed-instances of the DB.

If using the "new db migration" method, you can do the update of existing nil-values in that migration.