# How do I add a default value to columns in an existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a default value to a column through a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration)

I know it wouldn't affect existing data, but for every record going forward, I would like for there to be a default value - i.e. not `null` to be stored in the column.

How do I do that for existing columns without having to drop the columns?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627156/adding-default-true-to-boolean-in-existing-rails-column/8627171#8627171

Answer (score 1):

Following the links in the comments, this works for me:

```
change_table :my_model do |t|
     t.change_default :my_column, 0
end
```

Where `0` is the default value I wanted to set - and `:my_column` is the name of the column.

Additional Info can be found in the [API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-change_default)

Comment: Keep in mind that on MySQL this will change existing NULL values to the new default, but not on Postgres.

Comment: Interesting. Will keep that in mind.