# Jquery add star rating on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow a tutorial from [Adding a 5 star ratings feature to a Rails 4 model](http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/25/5-star-ratings-with-rails/) made by [@Simpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521411/simpleton) and I cannot successfully create the model for the tutorial.

When I type `rails g model Rating comment:references user:references score:integer default: 0` it will create the model. When I run `rake db:migrate` I receive an error message which says:

```
/db/migrate/20140107143726_create_ratings.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

What can I do? Is there a different way to set the default value for the integer named "score"?

**Update**

In **"db/migrate/20140107143726_create_ratings.rb"** I have:

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.references :review, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.integer :score
      t.string :default
      t.string :0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*I changed comment to review

Would this work?

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.references :review, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.integer :score, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

based on [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627156/adding-default-true-to-boolean-in-existing-rails-column), and [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue in your `/db/migrate/20140107143726_create_ratings.rb` migration.

Make sure that the `score` line in there looks something like:

`add_column :ratings, :score, :integer, default: 0`

**UPDATE**

Yes, this example should work:

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.references :review, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.integer :score, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay I updated my question. Im not sure the proper way to correct the _create_ratings.rb file.