# Rails migration requiring non-portable SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table which was originally defined with a default value for one column. I need to change or remove the default.

- [RubyOnRails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) seems (by its silence) to say this change is not wrapped for portability by `ActiveRecord::Migration`.
- [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) seems to say the SQL needed is not portable between MySQL and SQLite (my two DBs).

If I misread either of those, then straightening me out would be sufficient. Otherwise:

- From within an `ActiveRecord::Migration#up` routine, how can I write an `execute` call that's sensitive to the underlying DB? Can I, for instance, see the active values from `config/database.yml`?

Current table defn (from `db/schema.rb`) is:

```
  create_table "apis", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "endpoint"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "apiary_dev_domain"
    t.string   "resource_root",     default: "/v1", null: false
    t.text     "description"
  end
```

Comment: Which are the specifications of your column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding :default => true to boolean in existing Rails column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627156/adding-default-true-to-boolean-in-existing-rails-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Brad Werth:; you were right, this is effectively a dupe of [Adding default => true to boolean in existing Rails column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627156/adding-default-true-to-boolean-in-existing-rails-column).

ActiveRecord::Migration#change_column did the trick. Specifically, my migration script is:

```
class DeslashifyUrlComponentsInApi < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :apis, :resource_root, :string, default: "v1", null: false
  end
  def down
    change_column :apis, :resource_root, :string, default: "/v1", null: false
  end
end
```