# Is it possible to add default value to existing column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I did scaffold without adding default value.
Is there any possible way to add only default value to existing column?
If so, how can I write in migration file?

The value that I want to add default value, is 'country_id' column in profiles table.

thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration ?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto Thanks for pointing out! Do you know which on was correct answer???

Comment: that one `change_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false`