# Query to define a default value in a database migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this SO article I can see how to add a default value to a certain table:

[Add a default value to a column through a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration)

```
change_column :shops, :currency_id, :integer, :default => 1
```

I have another table currencies that has an ID and also a ISO_Name.  I want the system to use EUR as default value.  But it's possible that this has ID 5 or ID 1 or ...

So my question:  How can I define a default value that is based on the result of a query?  For example Currency.find_by_iso_code('EUR').id

Comment: if you have the field as iso_name, then why you are using iso_code. It can be done that you have mentioned change_column :shops, :currency_id, :integer, :default => Currency.find_by_iso_name('EUR').id

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's as easy as that!  Currency.find_by_iso_name('EUR').id works.  If you add this as I'll mark as answer.

Comment: good to know that it worked. By the way I have added it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have iso_name field in the currencies, you can achieve it by the following code.

```
change_column :shops, :currency_id, :integer, :default => Currency.find_by_iso_name('EUR').id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class SetDefaultCurrencyForShops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    currency = Currency.find_by_iso_code('EUR')
    if currency
      change_column :shops, :currency_id, :integer, :default => currency.id
    end
  end
end
```