# How to delete an attribute from a Devise user in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I have a devise model that differs from the default. It has extra attributes.

For example, my devise user has an email, password, and also a career. I'd like to write a line of code that will delete the career from the currently signed in user. I like to imagine that it would look something like this

```
current_user.career.delete
```

This would ideally empty the career from the database, so that `current_user.career` would then return `nil` until the user is updated again to add a career.

How can I do this?

Comment: well this should already work, it's a valid syntax

Comment: Hm, I have not found documentation on the github for devise. However, when I try to run this code, I get the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)`

Comment: could you add the relation between career and user model to the question

Comment: also make sure that `current_user.career` it self works fine

Comment: `puts current_user.career` outputs as expected. I added `career` to the devise user model using strong parameters and the sanitizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete method take the id or array of ids as parameter so you can simply use

```
current_user.career = nil
current_user.save
```

or you can set career to nil by create migration, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration)

```
change_column :users, :career, :string, :default => nil
```

see the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) to learn more.

Comment: Actually, this does not work because it only changes the value of current_user.career, it does not actually delete the information from the database.

Comment: I also don't think I can use change_column because I want to do this as part of a larger script rather than in a separate migration.