# Reversible migration for change_column_default from not having any default in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

The [Rails guides to active record migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns) says that you can do

```
change_column_default :products, :approved, from: true, to: false
```

I've got a `change` method in Rails that's similar to the following:

```
change_column_default :people, :height, from: nil, to: 0
```

with the intention of going from not having any defaults, to having a default of zero.

However, when I try rolling it back, I get

```
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
```

Considering I give Rails a `from` and `to`, why isn't it accepting it?

I'm using Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: Could it be that Rails is trying to avoid a type coercion issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration

Comment: I don't see any `from` or `to` parameters in the [method definition](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default)

Comment: @JonathanAllard assuming that `from` and `to` are hash keys, rather than optional arguments, they wouldn't appear in the method definition.

Comment: @JonathanAllard how do you know that the method you link to is the one called by the `change_column_default` call within `ActiveRecord::Migration`?

Comment: Is it possible that the column is not nullable?

Comment: Speculation: the edge guides and Rails 4 guides may be saying different things, and that's because things have changed between Rails 4 and Rails edge.

Comment: **Using `from` and `to` was added in Rails 5+ in this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20018/files**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Using `from` and `to` was [added](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20018/files) in Rails 5+

The guide linked to in the question is for Edge Rails, not for a released version of Rails.

Reversible syntax for `change_column_default` is the result of pull request [20018](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20018/files). The pull request also updated the Rails guides for Edge Rails.

From `activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb`:

```
-      def change_column_default(table_name, column_name, default)
+      # Passing a hash containing +:from+ and +:to+ will make this change
+      # reversible in migration:
+      #
+      #   change_column_default(:posts, :state, from: nil, to: "draft")
+      #
+      def change_column_default(table_name, column_name, default_or_changes)
```

The pull request was made June 27, 2015, which is more recent than any version of Rails released as of August 1, 2015.

The documentation for [migration for Rails 4.2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.3/active_record_migrations.html) reflects the fact that reversible syntax is not yet available:

```
change_column_default :products, :approved, false
```

Answer (score 17):

if you are using mysql as adapter, then according to this link http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter/change_column_default, your `change_column_default` migration runs like this

```
def change_column_default(table_name, column_name, default) #:nodoc:
 column = column_for(table_name, column_name)
 change_column table_name, column_name, column.sql_type, :default => default
end
```

so as you see it calls `change_column` within itself when you call `change_column_default` and  according to this link 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html
 `change_column` migration is irreversible.

This shows why you get `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`

So if you want to run migration using `change_column_default` you have to add `def up` and `def down`.

I would suggest to use change_column as it is already been called within change_column_default.

```
def up
 change_column :people, :height, :integer, default: 0
end

def down
 change_column :people, :height, :integer, default: nil
end
```

Comment: This answer isn't perfect, but it's better than the other answers (obviously, I can't award the bounty to myself).

Comment: yes @AndrewGrimm you are right regarding perfect answer. i added  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ as reference which is yet to be realesed. Still for adding information, i checked this link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder.html to see the list of reversible migrations. and i see `change_column` is not available in the list. lastly thank you for the bounty and thanks for your answer as well. helpful..:)

Answer (score 4):

### If you have an issue with migration file, Change your migration to this format.

```
change_column_default :table_name, :column_name, from: nil, to: "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct 2016, This feature (using `to:` and `from:` for `change_column_default` to be reversible) is now available on the 5.x branch. Unfortunately it's not available 4.2.x or lower. :(

Verification: `git tag --contains f9c841927ac3d1daea2a9cebf08b18e844e5eec5` in the rails project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as [Jonathan Allard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720164/jonathan-allard) said the `from` and `to` are not in the method source which means that the `change_column_default` doesn't accepts it. It is simply like this:

```
def sum(a)
  return a
end
```

Now if you try and pass two variables to it like `sum(a, b)` or anything it will not accept that right. This what you are trying to do above using `from` and `to`.

Now the correct syntax of this is:

```
change_column_default(:people, :height, 0)
```

The method doesn't accepts `from` and `to`(as it is defined as such, even if they are hash keys, if the method doesn't uses that key value pair anywhere then it is of no use to it) and if it is a new column the obviously it will have default value `nil`(if not set before) and suppose if the column `height` if of type `integer` and you give it default value `a` it will store `0` as the default value (not 100% sure but have tried doing this from rails console). It doesn't matters to rails what the default value currently is, it just needs the new default value. So if the current default value be `0` and you set it to `nil` rails will not complaint. It is your database and you wish what to do with it. Just if the database interrupts it if you are doing something wrong like assigning `string` to `boolean` then it will obviously throw error.

Now once this migration has ran then it will set the default value to `0` now rails doesn't know what the previous default value was. As it is gone and it has not store that anywhere. So that is why `change_column_default` is a irreversible migration. And if you try to roll it back it gives you `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` in case of `change` method. Means when you have used:

```
def change
  change_column_default(:people, :height, 0)
end
```

So that is why for this kind of migrations we use the method `up` and `down`:

```
def up
  change_column_default(:people, :height, 0)
end

def down
  change_column_default(:people, :height, nil)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `from: nil, to: 0` is the same as `{:from => nil, :to => 0}`, which is a single object.

Comment: Actually I think you didn't get my point, the `change_column_default` accepts only a single value for setting the default value of column, now instead of that you are writing `from: nil` so it has no code written in the source which will process your `from: nil` and `to: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a few points.  If you are stuck with the Rails version not supporting reversible change_column_default, one option to get past the problem is:

```
def change
    # If your dataset is small, just cache in memory, if large, consider file dump here:
    cache = Table.all
    # Full column def important for reversibility
    remove_column :table, :column, :type, { config_hash }
    # Re-add the column with new default:
    add_column  :table, :column, :type, { config_hash, default: 0 }
    # Now update the data with cached records (there might be more efficient ways, of course):
    cache.each do |rec|
        Table.find(rec.id).update(column: rec.column)
    end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

When you try to downgrade the data type , from `value` (0) to `nil` in this case , rails will complain this error. Because it might lose data

Another example would be going from `string` -> `integer`.

this is a really [good article explain the same](https://ariejan.net/2008/05/06/the-migration-that-cannot-be-undone-irreversible-migration/)

## UPDATE

It seems like your reverse migration calls `change_column_default` in `command_recorder` `(activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb#76)` please check if you set the `nil` as the default value.

## UPDATE2

it turns out that, if you use `change` in migrations, those have to be able to reversible

but change_column is not reversible through `change` method. So you will have to use the old rails migration method with `up` and `down`

read this article explain the [scenario](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/178-reversible-migrations-with-active-record)

Comment: `0` and `nil` are not data types. Also, you've mentioned the general concept of an irreversible migration, but you don't explain why this change would be an irreversible migration.

Comment: Where would I have set `nil` as the default value?

Comment: The method I called was `change_column_default`, not `change_column`.