# default value is not saved to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add a default value to an existing column in my database, this is my attempt:

```
add_column :users, :gamelv1, :integer, default: 1
```

I added `default: 1` and run `rake db:migrate`, but when I check the default value of the `gamelv1` column, it is still `nil`.  The value `1` I added is not saved.

How do I set default values for my column?

Comment: If the column already exists, `add_column` shouldn't even succeed. Did the migration run without errors? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration might be helpful, too.

Comment: You should first remove the column and then do this. This will work if you drop and create the database, and then run the migration, but you will of couse loose the data. You can also try to create a new object. If it's one, than it's ok. The existing objects need to be updated manually. Run User.all.each do |u| u.update_attributes(gamelv1: 1)

Answer (score 2):

The `default` value is only applied when a record is first created.  Existing records would be unaffected by a change to `default`.  You can manually apply this default value in your migration, by doing this:

```
add_column :users, :gamelv1, :integer, default: 1

User.reset_column_information

User.where(gamelv1: nil).update_all(gamelv1: 1)
```

This will find all records in which `gamelv1` is nil (null in the database), and will update those records so that `gamelv1` has the default value of `1`.  That way, your data is migrated at the same time as the database structure, so that you app behaves as you expect, regardless of when the record was created.