# Rails - Add default value after rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I added new migration that add a new column to a table. I ran the command 'rake db:migrate' Then I realize that I forgot to add a default value. How can I add default value after the rake db:migrate? (I'm storing the server on heroku service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `rake db:rollback`, then adjust your migration with default value, commit and push to heroku, and then run db:migrate again.

Another option is to create a new migration and use change_column_default:

```
  change_column_default :table_name, :column_name, "Default value"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create another migration

```
change_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
```

Same question as [Add a default value to a column through a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098602/add-a-default-value-to-a-column-through-a-migration)